# R6016 - not enough space for thread data error generated for javaws.exe

Tags: java, windows-7, java-8, java-web-start, msvcrt

We have an application deployed/launched by Web Start on Windows 7 desktops (Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1).

The version of Web Start used has previously been 1.6.0_22 32 bit (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\bin\javaws.exe) with no issues or errors seen.

Running the app against Web Start 1.8.0_66 32 bit (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\javaws.exe) results in the following:- 
- intermittent display of one or more popup R6016 error messages (see image below), i.e. sometimes no error at all, sometimes one error message, sometimes multiple error messages. On every occasion i.e. whether no error/one error/multiple errors the application login screen is presented, the user is able to login to the application which functions as normal. Error message(s) if present typically clear from display shortly after application login screen is displayed, which (via Task Manager -> Processes) is when jp2launcher.exe takes over from javaws.exe to execute the app.

Looking at [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126709) this appears consistent with javaws.exe using a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library (msvcrt20.dll?) and that this library generates the error message(s) if it encounters problems allocating memory for javaws.exe thread data. I'm speculating that javaws.exe itself retries internally for space for thread data until it succeeds hence the application itself succeeds in running.

I can see references to R6016 here and elsewhere but none for javaws.exe in this context - looking at the Microsoft documentation link, is there an issue with the way javaws.exe handles thread local storage?

This issue is with our Windows team here to resolve, but I'd be interested to know if anyone else has encountered this specifically for javaws.exe, their take on this and, of course, any resolutions...

[R6016 - not enough space for thread data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2dmK.png)